# error "attempt to index a boolean value" in file writing

Tags: lua

i wanna seperate two matrices into two csv file, such as 1.csv and 2.csv

```
data = [[
        1 2 3
        4 5 6
        7 8 9

    2 3 4
    5 7 8
    9 1 2

    ]]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local cc = table.concat
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function save_csv(filenumber,t)
  io.open(filenumber .. '.csv','w'):write(cc(t,'\n')):close()
end
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local filenumber = 1
local ans = {}
for line in (data..'\n'):gmatch '(.-)\n' do
  local s = {}
  for item in line:gmatch '%d+' do s[#s+1] = item end
  if #s > 0 then
    ans[#ans+1] = cc(s,',')
  elseif #ans > 0 then
    save_csv(filenumber,ans)
    filenumber = filenumber + 1
    ans = {}
  end
end
```

after above code, only 1.csv generated with the error:  attempt to index a boolean value
stack traceback:
    1.lua:22: in function 'save_csv'
    1.lua:34: in main chunk, I thought it may be some wrong in the data, can somebody help me?

Comment: The function chain `io.open():write():close()` doesn't work in Lua 5.1 because `write` returns `true`

Comment: Thanks lot! so the question is how can i update my Lua 5.1 to Lua 5.2 in SciTE?

Comment: Last version of SciTE embeds Lua 5.3

Comment: I get SciTE Version 4.2.3 , is this the last version? 4.2.3 only embeds Lua 5.1? Confused me!

Comment: Yes, starting from SciTE 4, it embeds Lua 5.3 (for internal SciTE scripts).

Comment: why I still can't find lua5.3? Maybe reinstall it is the way to handle the problem.

Comment: But how do you run your program?  Are you using external Lua executable?  What command is stored in your `Options`-`Edit properties`-`Open lua.properties` in the `command.go.*.lua` line?

Comment: # compatible with LuaBinaries for Lua 5.1; will work on both platforms.
command.compile.*.lua=luac5.3 -o "$(FileName).luc" "$(FileNameExt)"
# Lua 5.1
command.go.*.lua=lua5.3 "$(FileNameExt)"

Comment: the setting is wrong, i guess.

Comment: Try to run `print(_VERSION)`